# Use ant <apply> to run alfresco-mmt on a set of modules

Tags: ant, module, alfresco, apply

At the moment, our customization for Alfresco 3.4.x includes six AMP files, the removal of the internal log4j jar, the patching of a couple of jars to correct a bug in CIFS implementation, and a dozen configuration files. So far I have been using a shell script for the build, but now I am switching to ant to be compatible with our internal guidelines.

The injection of the modules works if I mention them explicitly, e.g.

```
<java dir="." fork="true" jar="${mmt.jar.location}">
    <arg line="install ${amp.dir}/cma-alfresco-3.4.6-E-0.amp ${dist.dir}/alfresco.war -force -verbose -nobackup"/>
</java>
```

Anyway, if I try to loop over all the modules placed in a directory,

```
<apply executable="java" dir="${build.dir}" failonerror="true">
    <fileset dir="${amp.dir}">
        <include name="*.amp" />
    </fileset>
    <arg value="-jar" />
    <arg value="${mmt.jar.location}"/>
    <arg value="install"/>
    <srcfile/>
    <arg value="${dist.dir}/alfresco.war"/>
    <arg value="-force"/>
    <arg value="-verbose"/>
    <arg value="-nobackup"/>
</apply>
```

I get an error `[apply] 04130000 Error whilst saving modifications file`. Here is an excerpt from the console:

```
[apply] Installing AMP 'C:\Users\***\Documents\workspace\AMP_***\amps\cma-alfresco-3.4.6-E-0.amp' into WAR './build/dist/alfresco.war'
[apply] Adding files relating to version '1.22.0' of module 'RemoteAlfrescoAPIrivet'
[apply]    - File '/WEB-INF/lib/cma-alfresco-3.4.6-E-0.jar' added to war from amp
[apply]    - File '/WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar' added to war from amp
[...]
[apply]    - File '/WEB-INF/classes/castor/mapping/workflowservice.createpackage.mapping.xml' added to war from amp
[apply]    - Directory '/WEB-INF/classes/castor/mapping' added to war
[apply]    - Directory '/WEB-INF/classes/castor' added to war
[apply] 04130000 Error whilst saving modifications file.
[apply] Module managment tool available commands:
[apply] -----------------------------------------------------------
[apply] install: Installs a AMP file(s) into an Alfresco WAR file, updates if an older version is already installed.
[apply] usage:   install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation> [options]
[apply] valid options: 
[apply]    -verbose   : enable verbose output
[apply]    -directory : indicates that the amp file location specified is a directory.
[apply]                 All amp files found in the directory and its sub directories are installed.
[apply]    -force     : forces installation of AMP regardless of currently installed module version
[apply]    -preview   : previews installation of AMP without modifying WAR file
[apply]    -nobackup  : indicates that no backup should be made of the WAR
[apply] -----------------------------------------------------------
[apply] list:  Lists all the modules currently installed in an Alfresco WAR file.
[apply] usage: list <WARFileLocation>
[apply] -----------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\***\Documents\SDP\workspace\AMP_***\build.xml:83: apply returned: 1
```

I also tried to switch on the `spawn` attribute of the `apply` task, but the only effect I got was to loose the standard output.

I am aware that the `apply` task is likely to have a different behaviour than `java` task, but I don't understand what difference may cause this error; so, any idea to debug this problem is welcome, I would love to avoid explicitely mentioning all the modules and being just able to drop then in a directory.

Comment: Could it be that in the 'working' example you have `dir="."`, but in the `apply` case you have `dir="${build.dir}"`, hence they are not quite the same?

Comment: Oh, thank you, _that_ escaped me, and it might have been a problem... but it wasn't, since I still get exactly the same problem. Can't be I'm surprised, since the main difference would have been in generated file paths, but the `relative` attribute of the `apply` tag defaults to `true`...

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen the error *Error whilst saving modifications file* before, it is related to the fact that the MMT is expecting a directory `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/<moduleid>` to exist inside the webapp.

I would try creating the directory `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/RemoteAlfrescoAPIrivet` (either manually or via Ant) and try running the command again.

Comment: This does not help either. Even if it did, it would have been a problem to automatically create the directories before inserting the amp, since the directory name is in the AMP itself... anyway, it doesn't matter: it simply Doesn't Work :-(